# SolrCloud: Underlying file changed by external force?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Having trouble with an issue I am unable to reproduce in solrcloud. Seems to happen at random.

```
Underlying file changed by an external force at 2018-09-18T14:55:22Z, (lock=NativeFSLock(path=/path/to/my/shard/index/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive valid],creationTime=2018-09-18T14:55:22.006973Z)) Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Underlying file changed by an external force at 2018-09-18T14:55:21Z,
```

the index is schemaless and typically receives many simultaneous updates.

It usually starts with something like this: (in this order before the write.lock error occurs)

```
Error from server at server3/solr/myshard: Bad Request
Remote error message: Exception writing document id bc04df6e-f29f-4091-ad73-f708a97d28b4 to the index; possible analysis error.
3 Async exceptions during distributed update:
Remote error message: this IndexWriter is closed
```

Is there anyway to self recover from the indexwriter being closed? After the error occurs, no more documents can be written to the collection. The only solution I have right now is to either delete the write.lock and restart solr or recreate the collection completely.

Comment: Are you running multiple nodes with the same data directory?

Comment: they have the same directory name, but different shard names. i.e. server1:/my/data/shard1, server2:/my/data/shard2, server3:/my/data/shard3 - /my/data/ being on their own independent drives

Comment: Are these drives local, or are they mounted through a network file protocol (NFS, iSCSI, etc.)? If something touches or changes the metadata about the lock file, that could trigger the error you're seeing above. It's an underlying Lucene protection to avoid fubaring your index if something has happened outside of Lucene itself. Usually this happens when data is touched outside of Lucene, such as through kubernetes/docker/network file systems/etc.

Comment: I don't think the drives are local. They are mounted drives on azure cloud. Is the access time and ctime being so close a coincidence? If these changes are not preventable, is there a way to trigger recovery? (even if it means botching the current updates)